# MOSFET on-state characteristics

Tags: mosfet

In MOSFET datasheets they often lists parameters like V<sub>GS</sub> (ON) , I<sub>d</sub> (ON). Is V<sub>GS</sub> (ON) is the testing gate- source voltage that is being used (of course above threshold voltage) or it's a particular constant gate-source voltage which turns the MOSFET FULLY TURN ON? similarly what is this on state drain current?

As far as I know the degree of "on-ness" depends on the gate voltage, so what does it mean to have a "on" state drain current I<sub>d</sub> on? It is meaningless because the degree of "on-ness" depends on the user hence, different degree means different drain current. So, is on state drain current is the saturation drain current for a testing gate voltage?

Comment: **\$RD_{on}\$** is an attempt to simplify MOSfets for logic-like *on/off* application. You're wanting to look more closely at on-ness, so go to the MOSfet's detailed data sheet.

Comment: I've **never** seen the term V_GS(ON) used in any MOSFET data sheet. Ditto V_DS(ON) and I_d(ON) so, what you should perhaps do is link a data sheet that does list these things even if it's just for fixing my incompetence in these matters.

Comment: You've also stated \$V_{GS}(ON)\$ twice so I assumed you meant one of those to be \$V_{DS}(ON)\$ which would be preferably written as \$V_{DS(ON)}\$ if it has any actual meaning (sorry for not knowing it).

Comment: @Andy aka I might be wrong with the term V_GS(ON) pardon for that. Could you please elaborate other two parameters?

Comment: There's nothing to elaborate due to my incompetence of never seeing these parameters in a data sheet hence, why I asked you to show a data sheet with these mentioned.

Comment: *particular constant gate-source voltage which turns the MOSFET FULLY TURN ON?* No, **in theory**, as you increase \$V_{GS}\$, the resistance (\$R_{DS,on}\$) will decrease. The limit is the **maximum** \$V_{GS}\$, if you go above that, the gate oxide is damaged. So in practice you need to apply as much \$V_{GS}\$ as is feasible (maximum your circuit can deliver but not exceeding \$V_{GS,max}\$) and that gives you a certain \$R_{DS,on}\$.

Comment: @Andy aka see here: https://mhtml.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf2/50067/FAIRCHILD/2N7000/405/1/2N7000.html?lang=en ,  see on-state drain current and on state drain-source voltage

Comment: @Sayan not once does the term VGS(ON) (or variations) exist in that data sheet

Comment: @Andy aka yes as said in the comment I was wrong,  but how about other two parameters?

Comment: @Andy aka,  I am saying yes GS (ON)  doesn't exist so leave it,  but how about on state drain current and on state vds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *@Andy aka see here:
> mhtml.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf2/50067/FAIRCHILD/2N7000/405/1/… , see
> on-state drain current and on state drain-source voltage*

The only occurrence of the term \$I_{D(ON)}\$ in the data sheet for the Fairchild 2N7000 is here: -

[image]

And the reason why most MOSFET data sheets don't list this value is because it can be easily extracted from the MOSFET forward characteristic seen here (with added red and blue lines): -

[image]

For \$V_{DS(ON)}\$ the only occurrence is here: -

[image]

And, if you look at the same MOSFET forward characteristic (as above) you'll see that ties in with the purple markings I've added to it below: -

[image]

> *As far as I know the degree of "on-ness" depends on the gate voltage,
> so what does it mean to have a "on" state drain current Id on?*

Correct and that is why most data sheets place emphasis on the forward characteristic curve because those (extremely) rarely mentioned parameters can be found in that graph. The forward characteristic graph tells you many many things and, you can easily interpolate as I have done.

Comment: to be specific just can you explain this alone : what is Id (ON)) ?  As mentioned in the data sheet , here is my assumption : they are choosing a particular TEST GS voltage and a particular TEST DS voltage, and now measuring the drain current under this condition and lists this as Id (ON) , is this true?

Comment: \$I_{D(ON}\$ is measured (in the data sheet) at a gate source voltage of 4.5 volts. 4.5 volts is chosen because it represents a decent lower limit value of a standard 5 volt digital signal. So, with 4.5 volts applied and sufficient drain source voltage, you can typically expect the drain current to be 600 mA @Sayan. So, yes, it is true but, remember that the graph and value quoted are typical values. In the table, the drain current might be as low as 75 mA in extremes.

Comment: what do you mean by "sufficient"? Do you mean the voltage which can take the mosfet in saturation region corresponding to GS=4. 5 V?

Comment: @Sayan yes, sufficient drain source voltage needs to be applied or you will be in the linear region where the current isn't constant. So, \$V_{DS}\$ at 10 volts ensures the MOSFET is saturated.

Comment: sorry for my late reply, I think now it's clear. Answer is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The on-ness of a MOSFET depends on the Gate-Source voltage, the threshold voltage and the Drain-Source voltage. It is meaningful because if you have resistors connected to the circuit, there will be a voltage drop on each resistor which will depend on ID and the Source voltage may change according to that changing the on-ness.

Because in the comments there is a lot of confusion, let's go through the basics: A MOSFET can work as a voltage-controlled resistor when Vgs-Vth>Vds and we don't have a source resistor. If we have a source resistor, the resistance still changes with Vgs but not as much. When Vds>Vgs-Vth a MOSFET is a current source which depends on Vgs.